# Loading nib view into another nib view

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I have two `UIViews`, let me called them as `A` and `B`. `A` is the container of `B` and each one is created using Interface Builder.

I need to add my `B` view into `A` using interface builder, like this image:

[image: A UIView created using interface builder]

[image: B UIView created using interface builder]

The problem is that the view is loaded but it's empty, when I debugged it I saw that every component is created.

The `B` `UIView` class definition is:

B.h (ISMSliderCustomizable.h)

```
@interface ISMSliderCustomizable : UIView {

    IBOutlet UIView *view;
    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
    IBOutlet UILabel *minLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *maxLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *tooltip;
    IBOutlet UILabel *sliderValue;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic) float min;
@property (nonatomic) float max;
@property (nonatomic) float initialValue;

@end
```

B.m (ISMSliderCustomizable.m)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ISMSliderCustomizable" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ISMSliderCustomizable" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
```

I need to add a `UIView` into another `UIView` which every `UIView` is created with IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is UIView in b.xib is 320x480
but View B in a.xib is not
so it's not empty,it just out of range

Comment: I decided to create the subview by code, I don't want to waste my time anymore with IB. Thanks.